# Show integral minor than

Tags: integration

Show that this is true:

$$\int_1^x\frac{\sin t}{t}dt - x +1 < 0, x>1$$

I'm totally stuck, I think you should use $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 1$ but I can't figure out if it's correct or wich way to do it.

Comment: If we write the inequality as $$\int_1^x \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt < x-1,$$ do you see it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the left hand side, then $f'(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x} - 1 < 0$ since $\sin x < 1 < x$. So $f$ decreases, and $f(x) < f(1) = 0$ QED.

Alternately: $\dfrac{\sin t}{t} < 1$ for $x > 1$. So $\int_{1}^x \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt < \int_{1}^x 1 dt = x - 1$ and this also implies the conclusion.